# Why does this ZINTERSTORE command not perform a SUM?

Tags: redis, redis-py

I am reading [Josiah Carlson's Redis in Action book](https://redislabs.com/redis-in-action/).

In chapter 2 he re-scales the members of a ZSET to half of their original scores using the following statement in Python:

```
conn.zinterstore('viewed:', {'viewed:': .5})
```

My main issue with this is as follows:

The default aggregation function is `SUM` **so wouldn't this just end up adding the scores to the scores I already have ?**

Wouldn't the scores be `SCORE + 0.5 * SCORE` ?

**Why is it just overwriting the value ?**

Github link to code [here](https://github.com/josiahcarlson/redis-in-action/blob/4b40bd25606e0c2edc72f57bb9f8dcae16c87874/python/ch02_listing_source.py#L185).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking of this as the intersection of the `viewed:` set with itself—an intersection of two sets. In fact, since there's only one element in the second argument, there's only one set in the intersection. Every element of that set is therefore in the intersection, and its score is weighted by 0.5.

Perhaps you were thrown off by the fact that the first argument is `viewed:`? That's just the destination key to be saved to, it doesn't participate in the intersection. You can see how the Python arguments are mapped to Redis arguments [here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/f001927f91ba3c22cb892bbf1e39b34fd47693bc/redis/client.py#L3015).

Going at it from the other direction, this is what the code would actually look like if it was computing `SCORE + 0.5 * SCORE`:

```
conn.zinterstore('viewed:', {`viewed:': 1, 'viewed:': .5})
```